# SQL-Using JOINS to get the values from three tables

Tags: sql, linq

I have used four tables, namely VehicleMaster, OwnerMaster, CustomerMaster and CustomerVehicle in my project

As name explains, first three are master tables and last table (CustomerVehicle) contains CustomerID & VehicleID. The table hierarchy are as follows

```
 OwnerMaster (OwnerID, OwnerName) 
 VehicleMaster (VehicleID, OwnerID, VehicleDetails blah blah...) 
 CustomerMaster (CustomerID, CustomerName..) 
 CustomerVehicle     (CustomerID, VehicleID)
```

Now i would like to get how many vehicles are running under each owner. output should be something like this.

```
OwnerName, TotalVehicles, No of Running Vehicles, NonRunning Vehicles.
xxxx, 40, 34, 6
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: SQL and Linq are two very distinct syntaxes for queries. Which are you looking for?

Comment: With the help of left outer join, i can get the first three values, rest of the columns, I need some guidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be owners without vehicles, we don't know... something like this should work as well:

```
SELECT 
  om.OwnerName,
  count(vm.VehicleID) Total,
  sum(case when vm.VehicleID is not null 
            and cv.VehicleID is not null then 1 else 0 end) Runnng,
  sum(case when vm.VehicleID is not null 
            and cv.VehicleID is null then 1 else 0 end) NotRunnng
FROM OwnerMaster om
LEFT JOIN VehicleMaster vm ON om.OwnerID = vm.OwnerID
LEFT JOIN CustomerVehicle cv ON vm.VehicleID = cv.VehicleID
GROUP BY om.OwnerName
```

Comment: Thanks Elhana, But still the above mentioned issue is there.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use joins and no subqueries? I can think of ways to do it with joins only, but it will be stupid.

Comment: With subquery: LEFT JOIN (select distinct VehicleID from CustomerVehicle) cv ON vm.VehicleID = cv.VehicleID

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work; left join the tables and (distinct) count the respective fields;

```sql
SELECT om.OwnerName, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT vm.VehicleID) TotalVehicles, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT cv.VehicleID) Running, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT vm.VehicleID)-COUNT(DISTINCT cv.VehicleID) NotRunning
FROM OwnerMaster om
LEFT JOIN VehicleMaster vm ON om.OwnerID = vm.OwnerID
LEFT JOIN CustomerVehicle cv ON vm.VehicleID = cv.VehicleID
GROUP BY om.OwnerID, om.OwnerName
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43b28/1).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. However, I am getting wrong result and I analyze the query later I found the issue where it is. See the below SQLFiddle link to understand the problem.  <br/>[SQLFiddle Updated](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa000/1)  <br/> TotalVehicle count for Owner1 is wrong. It should be 3. Out of which I should get the Running and non-running. Hope this helps to understand the pbm

Comment: @BlueMoon Yes, as I said the query works if the vehicle is assigned to a single customer at a time, your sample assigns vehicle 1 to customer 1,2,3 at the same time in `CustomerVehicle`.

Comment: @BlueMoon Updated with a query that is more resilient to duplicates (ie several customers can be linked to a single vehicle at once)

Comment: Hi,  I have used Isactive field to make one customer vehicle is active at a time.

Comment: @BlueMoon You should update your question with what logic you want on IsActive, it's not even mentioned anywhere except your SQLfiddle.

Comment: Yes after read your comments, i added the field to avoid duplicates. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Elhana. I have updated my query to get the exact result what i need. Modified query as:

```
    SELECT 
    om.OwnerName,
    count(vm.VehicleID) Total,
    sum(case when vm.VehicleID is not null 
        and cv.VehicleID is not null then 1 else 0 end) Runnng,
     sum(case when vm.VehicleID is not null 
        and cv.VehicleID is null then 1 else 0 end) NotRunnng
    FROM OwnerMaster om
    LEFT JOIN VehicleMaster vm ON om.OwnerID = vm.OwnerID and vm.isactive = 1
    LEFT JOIN (select distinct VehicleID from CustomerVehicle where isactive = 1) cv
    ON vm.VehicleID = cv.VehicleID
    where om.isactive = 1
    GROUP BY om.OwnerName
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52839/1)